# Showing data and provide selection from database by using datagridview combobox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am pulling data from my database to my datagridview. For the column "Quantity", I want to make it as combobox so that users can choose the quantity they want.

But now I cannot see the option that I create in the collection (at the design view"edit column") when I debugging. What I only found [on internet](http://vb.net-informations.com/datagridview/vb.net_datagridview_combobox.htm) is doing without binding data with the database. So is there any solution to my situation? Below is my code for this part:

```
 Private Sub CartSummary_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        conn.Open()
        sql = "SELECT f.name, od.quantity, f.price FROM Food f INNER JOIN [Order Detail] od ON f.id = od.food_id INNER JOIN [Order] o ON od.order_id = o.Id WHERE od.order_id = @oid AND o.customer_id = @cid ;"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oid", FoodMenu.OrderID)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", Login.userId)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            dgvOrderSummary.Rows.Add(dr.Item("name"), dr.Item("quantity"), dr.Item("price"))
        End While
        dr.Close()
        conn.Close()
    End Sub
```

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: That's not how you populate a `DataGridView` from a database. Firstly, populate a `DataTable` and bind it. Whether the data is coming from a database or not, bind the combo box column too. You can call `Fill` on a data adapter to populate a `DataTable` or call `Load` on the `DataTable` and pass a data reader.

Comment: As for the combo box column, check [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?541476) out. If you end up answering your own question, be sure to post an answer and accept it in order to help others.

Comment: How does the example you linked not help?  To my untrained eye your code here matches pretty close to what you've linked.  I would also suggest what you're got here is a pretty loose description of "binding" so don't really understand that part of your question.

Comment: How many items are there going to be in the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`? I would think, that using a combo box for a “Quantity” value may be awkward “depending” on how many items there are. Example, a combo box with 10 items 1,2, … 10 would allow the user to select from only ten (10) different “quantity” values. If the “quantity” values range from 1 to some large number like 100 or more… then a combo box may not be the best choice.

Comment: When you add a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to a `DataGridView`, the “column” itself can have a `DataSource.` This “column DataSource” is used to “fill” the combo box items list. After adding this column to the “GRID” and setting the “GRIDS” data source to the data returned from the DB… then one thing your code should look for “before” the data is bound to the grid… is making SURE there are NO “quantity” values coming from the DB, that are NOT in the “columns” data source.

Comment: Example, if the items in the combo box column are 1, 2, 3 and there is a row in the data base such that the “quantity” value is “4”… then the grid will throw a `DataError` when you attempt to set its data source. It is important for the code to check for this to avoid the exception.

Comment: Therefore, if you want to “bind” the combo box column to the “Quantity” column coming from the DB… then it would be wise to loop through all the “Quanity” values coming from the DB to make SURE all the quantity values actually “exist” in the combo box. If the code finds a quantity that is NOT already in the combo box… then you can simply add it. This should be done “before” binding the data to the “GRID.”

Comment: Quantity as a ComboBox is a fairly terrible idea from a UI point of view. Use a textbox unless you have an urgent need for keyboardless input?

Comment: Don't put spaces in database table names